# Bootstrap tour 0.4.0 is not showing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Just installed bootstrap-tour - however I don't think I'm implementing it correctly..

Here is the script at the bottom of my page ~ I have a header with id="test-tour"

```js
<h1 id="test-tour" style="font-weight:300; line-height:36px; font-size:24px; color:#1F69BA !important; text-shadow:none;text-align:center;padding-left:1px;">
   <b>INTERESTED IN APPLYING TO UNIVERSITY OR COLLEGE?</b>
</h1>

<script>

var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#test-tour",
    title: "Testing our tour steps...",
    content: "Hooray! It works!"
  }
]});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
  
</script>
```

in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

/* 
  *= require jquery.ui.effect-highlight 
  *= require bootstrap-tour 
*/

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js 
//= require bootstrap-tour

Comment: You might want to make sure your document is loaded and ready before running the above code. See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Did you include the library files?

Comment: I included the following:
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.effect-highlight
 *= require bootstrap-tour
*/
in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

and also
//= require bootstrap-tour in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: @AlexJohnson $(document).ready yielded the same results - thanks for the tip however!

Comment: Hmmmm... And I'm assuming you're not getting any console errors? Can you share your headers/included JS - it might be an issue with not loading all dependencies, or in the wrong order...

Comment: edited @AlexJohnson